# Android Studio build keeps crashing (stableIds.txt The data is invalid. (13))

Tags: java, android, crash, aapt

I've been trying to run my android studio app but android studio keeps giving me this build error for all of my projects.

Full error is this:

```
ERROR:: AAPT: <App Location>\app\build\intermediates\stable_resource_ids_file\debug\stableIds.txt: error: failed to open: The data is invalid. (13).
```

I tried making fresh projects too but that didn't seem to fix it. I didn't change anything in those projects. I also checked and there is no stableIds.txt. This issue didn't happen before too so I'm even more confused.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was experiencing the same issue... my anti virus program (AVG) was the culprit. AVG was silently preventing Android Studio from working properly...despite having already turned off AVG's `File Sheild`, and `Behaviour Sheild`. I fixed this by:

**solution 1**

1. turning off AVG's `Ransomeware Protection` should also prevent this from ever happening again.

   - (may also need to turn off `File Sheild` and `Behaviour Sheild` but I'm not sure, because I already had them turned off before this happened)
   - [i just looked at some of my AVG's settings for the first time....so much time wasted over the years....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ROGR.png)

**solution 2**

1. restarting my computer (only worked for me after i restarted for 2nd time)
2. open the project in android studio
3. try to deploy the app onto a device
4. wait for a popup from AVG to appear, asking if you want to prevent `aapt2.exe` from modifying `stableIds.txt`
5. allow it..
6. build the app without any issues!

Answer (score 3):

Most Likely an Anti-Virus problem

Temporarily disabling the anti-virus program for a few minutes solved this problem for me.

1. Close Project in Android Studio (File > Close Project)
2. Disable Anti-Virus.
3. Re-open the project and run the app.

Answer (score 3):

This Problem occurs when Ransomware Protection > Controlled Folder Access is turned on in Windows Defender. To fix it, Go to Windows Defender > Ransomware Protection and Turn Off `Controlled Folder Access`. If You have a different antivirus, they may also have similar settings which might prevent Android Studio from functioning normally.

This fix worked in my case...

Comment: this is exactly what was happening to me.  Ransomware protection to protect documents.  It's a .txt file.