# Cannot build a project in Android Studio with due to the stableIds.txt

Tags: android, android-studio, aapt

When I try to build my project in Android studio, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:AAPT: C:\Users\user\Documents\AndroidKurs\TrueOrFalse\app\build\intermediates\stable_resource_ids_file\debug\stableIds.txt:error: failed to open: The data is invalid. (13).
```

Please note that the solution in this topic does not work for me, I have even disabled Windows Defender completely and nothing has changed.
[Android Studio build keeps crashing (stableIds.txt The data is invalid. (13))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68443959/android-studio-build-keeps-crashing-stableids-txt-the-data-is-invalid-13)

Also, Android Studio is up to date. What could be the problem?

EDIT:
I forgot to add that I've disabled my antivirus as well, also tried to add an exception and nothing worked.

Comment: Do you have a antivirus running??

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add that I've disabled my antivirus as well, also tried to add an exception and nothing worked.

Comment: Since you have disabled the anti-virus now clean your project and also invalidate cache and restart the android studio. Then before building check the stableIds.txt is removed if not then manually delete this file(this is safe as it is under generated files). Then build your project.

Comment: Sadly, it didn't work